# Beginner in Javascript: How do I edit the an address in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I was given:

```
John, Doe, 36, 1234 Park st.
```

I made an object titled friend and input all the info.

```js
var friends = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 36, address:"1234 Park st."}
```

and want to change the address to `"1234 Park ln."`. Not sure how to proceed...

Comment: [___Working with objects___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

Answer (score 1):

```
friends.address = "1234 Park ln."
```

Answer (score 1):

In you case, you should be able to do:

```
var friends = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 36, address:"1234 Park st."}
friends.address = "1234 Park ln."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
friends.address = friends.address.replace('st','ln');
```

Comment: Why negative? It is just an option

Answer (score -1):

```
var friends = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 36, address:"1234 Park st."};

friends["address"] = "your new address comes here";
```

(or)

```
friends.address = "your new address comes here";
```